# Quick time player has a bug and doesn't play the video after a certain time in a long recording (around 1 hr)

Tags: macos, mac, video, quicktime

So I have online classes for 2 hours daily and I'm recording them using Quick Time player. Earlier it was working just fine. Now after a certain point (let's say 1hr 30 min) it gets stuck on a certain scene, so I can hear the audio, but it doesn't play the video.

I'm using Macbook Air, and my laptop is around 5 years old, but I cant change it before October, can someone please help. My computer I update my computer regularly, and I'm using version 10.5 of Quick Time.

Edit: It's not playing the video in other video players like VLC or Apple TV either

Comment: Does it play correctly in other programs like VLC?

Comment: @SolarMike, no it's not